# How to change the mp3's volume (levels) in Processing?

Tags: java, audio, arduino, processing

I want to make the simple sequencer with Processing and Arduino.

My ideal are:

1. Put on a rheostat on Arduino and send analog serial numbers to Processing.
2. The sound's volume will change along the analog number of rheostat on processing.

What I tried and done:

1. Import and use Minim.
2. Succeeded in sending analog number of rheostat from Arduino to Processing
3. Set the analog number on float volume
4. Use setGain(volume) on void loop() but volume didn't change.
5. Use setVolume(volume) on void loop() but volume didn't change.

The sound's volume changed only once when the sounds started to play.

I tried to use ESS but I couldn't import the library even I put it the folder of Processing's Libraries.

Can I change the volume with playing the sounds on Processing?

Here is my cord:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
int number;
float volume;

import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;

AudioPlayer player;
int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;

Minim minim;

void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem0000", 9600);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("music02.mp3", BUFFER_SIZE);
  volume = -60;

  player.setGain(-10);
  //player.setVolume(-10);

  delay(200);

  player.loop();

}


void draw() {
  player.setGain(volume);
  //player.setVolume(volume);
}


void serialEvent(Serial port) {
    println(port.read());
    volume = port.read();
    println(volume);
    delay(200);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the issue?? Update with things you tried..

Comment: I added my tried and done list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reading the value correctly from Arduino, but you're not scaling it/mapping it to what minim expects.

It looks like you're probably reading a byte from Arduino, so you have values from 0 to 255, but minim's [setVolume()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/Controller.html#setVolume-float-) expects a floating point value from 0.0 to 1.0

You can try something like this:

```
void serialEvent(Serial port) {
    println(port.read());
    volume = map(port.read(),0,255,0.0,1.0);
    println(volume);
    delay(200);
}
```

this would work the same as

```
void serialEvent(Serial port) {
    println(port.read());
    volume = port.read() / 255.0;
    println(volume);
    delay(200);
}
```

assuming your value from Arduino is from 0-255 (if you read the potentiometer with [analogRead()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead) you'll deal with values from 0-1023, so be sure to divide those by 4 before sending them to Processing.

One neat thing about using [map()](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) is that you can reverse the volume if you want:

```
volume = map(port.read(),0,255,1.0,0.0);
```

Have fun!

**Update**
baoga made a good point about setVolume not working.
I see this in console:

```
=== Minim Error ===
=== Volume is not supported.
```

Seems to be an issue with the Java code beneath Minim's hood that can't seem to control volume. As a workaround I suggest using [setGain()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioplayer_method_setgain.html) instead.
Bare in mind, this is in decibels (so the 0.0, 1.0 range does not apply).
Try removing the statements in `draw()` and replacing `serialEvent()` with something like this to test first:

```
void serialEvent(Serial port) {
    int arduinoValue = port.read();
    float gain = map(arduinoValue,0,255,-10.0,10.0);
    println("arduinoValue: " + arduinoValue + " gain: " + gain);
    player.setGain(gain);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.I could build it and control the number from 0.0 to 1.0 but the volume didn't change....

Comment: I could change the volume! Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! Please vote and/or mark the answer if it was helpful :)